# R: subsetting all observations of individuals that have one matched observation

Tags: r, indexing, subset

Sorry for another dang subsetting question; I just can't find this case described, though it must be common.  Boiled-down data looks like this:

```
Plot     Year  BA
A        1980  44
A        1990  54
A        2000  66
B        1980  58
B        1990  69
B        2000  80
```

I want all observations for any plot with BA < 50 in 1980 -- in the above, all three A rows.  I understand `subset(Df, BA<50 & Year==1980)` but can't figure out the next level of indexing.

Also if anyone has a better way to phrase the title I'll change it.  Every way I could think of to search on only turned up the &/| questions.  (So many &/| questions...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Index your condition on `Plot`, checking membership with `%in%` in case there is more than one `Plot` satisfying the condition in the real data.

```
subset(df, Plot %in% unique(Plot[BA < 50 & Year == 1980]))
#   Plot Year BA
# 1    A 1980 44
# 2    A 1990 54
# 3    A 2000 66
```

Or with standard evaluation `[` subsetting,

```
df[with(df, Plot %in% unique(Plot[BA < 50 & Year == 1980])), ]
#   Plot Year BA
# 1    A 1980 44
# 2    A 1990 54
# 3    A 2000 66
```

Comment: *Plot %in%*!!  I had tried your first example except for that crucial bit.  Extra thanks for giving both subset() and [ ] -- I also wanted that, having seen the Dangers of Subset discussion.  @Psidom I like that dplyr syntax better -- but that's for *after* I get my head around the regular indexing.

Comment: @uhClem - I made an edit, adding `unique` which I think will be more efficient when we have more than one match in the same group.

Answer (score 1):

Another option with `dplyr`, this assumes there is only one record equal to 1980 for each plot, otherwise you may want to wrap the condition with `all()` or `any()` depending on your desired logic:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% group_by(Plot) %>% filter(BA[Year == 1980] < 50)

# Source: local data frame [3 x 3]
# Groups: Plot [1]

#     Plot  Year    BA
#   <fctr> <int> <int>
# 1      A  1980    44
# 2      A  1990    54
# 3      A  2000    66
```

Under circumstances where multiple 1980 exist for some plots, the logic by @DirtySockSniffer's answer is equivalent to `df %>% group_by(Plot) %>% filter(any(BA[Year == 1980] < 50))` in `dplyr`.

Answer (score 1):

We can use `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[, if(all(BA[Year == 1980] < 50)) .SD, by = Plot]
#   Plot Year BA
#1:    A 1980 44
#2:    A 1990 54
#3:    A 2000 66
```